# laravel 5.5 return redirect route not working

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a strange issue with my laravel app .

I have a route defined as :

web.php

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => '/', 'uses' => 'LoginsController@getLogin']);
Route::post('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LoginsController@postLogin']);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['authenticate', 'roles']], function (){
    Route::get('/logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'LoginsController@getLogout']);
    Route::get('/dashboard','DashboardController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
});
```

In a controller , i'm trying to redirect to this route

LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginsController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $username = 'username';
    protected $redirectTo = '/';
    protected $guard = 'web';

    public function getLogin()
    {
        if (Auth::guard('web'))
        {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
        return view('login');
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $auth = Auth::guard('web')->attempt([
            'username' => $request->username,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'active' => 1]);
        if ($auth)
        {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
        return redirect()->route('/');
    }

    public function getLogout()
    {
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();
        return redirect()->route('/');
    }
}
```

Where I am typing http://localhost:8000 in address bar of browser. I see.

[image: When I am it runnig]

Comment: try return redirect('/'); since route() uses a named route

Comment: Consider turning on error reporting/debugging. I assume you're getting a 500 error somewhere.

Comment: Just fyi, Laravel has Auth built in: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication

Comment: Where is the 500 error?

Comment: I think this is not a redirection problem, may be  there is a error in the destination blade. Try to redirect to a blank blade

Comment: I think one of your middleware (authenticate or roles) redirect you to your login page instead of the dashboard once you're logged. That would explain why you have the error 500 `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Comment: It is not blank blade For  example I  write <h1>Hello World.</h1>

Comment: As I said previously, I suspect your middleware. Can you try to remove the middlewares `authenticates` and `roles` and tell us if you still experiment the error 500 ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS?